# Can't get String sent to PHP on server from Android

Tags: java, php, android, apache

I know the apache library is deprecated, but I was wondering if it is possible to send the string "ansi" in this code to a PHP script on a server at a URL. My code is below and I don't know what I'm missing.
Any help would be appreciated.
I've looked up a lot online and many people suggest using StringEntity, which I did, but it's still not working :/
I'm trying to retrieve a lot of data from the PHP but the PHP script needs the string "ansi" before data can be retrieved.

```
public class HttpServiceClass {
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> headers;
private String ansi;
private String url;
private int responseCode;
private String message;
private String response;

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return message;
}

public int getResponseCode() {
    return responseCode;
}

public HttpServiceClass(String url, String ansi) {

    this.url = url;
    this.ansi = ansi;
    params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
}

public void AddParam(String name, String value) {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

public void AddHeader(String name, String value) {
    headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

public void ExecuteGetRequest() throws Exception {
    String combinedParams = "";
    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        combinedParams += "?";
        for (NameValuePair p : params) {
            String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(), "UTF-8");
            if (combinedParams.length() > 1) {
                combinedParams += "&" + paramString;
            } else {
                combinedParams += paramString;
            }
        }
    }

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);
    for (NameValuePair h : headers) {
        request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }

    executeRequest(request, url, ansi);
}

public void ExecutePostRequest() throws Exception {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.setEntity(new StringEntity(ansi));
    for (NameValuePair h : headers) {
        request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }

    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
    }

    executeRequest(request, url, ansi);
}

private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url, String ansi) {
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 10000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 10000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: you can use volley network library

Comment: But is there a way to do it with the apache HTTP library?